# How to make if else PHP cleaner using a case/switch?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using an if-else statement inside my WordPress theme. I want a cleaner way of doing an IF and ELSE using a case/switch.

This is my current code:

```
            if($theme_measure_icon->slug == 'elektrisch-rijden'):
                $icon_class = 'icon--scooter';
            endif;

            if($theme_measure_icon->slug == 'efficient-laden'):
                $icon_class = 'icon--battery';
            endif;

            if($theme_measure_icon->slug == 'stadshubs'):
                $icon_class = 'icon--logistiek';
            endif;

<i class="icon <?= $icon_class; ?>"></i>
```

How can I do the same with a PHP class?

Comment: Do you need to use a class (or case/switch), or just looking for an alternative?

Comment: I need a switch/case I think it's cleaner and better for readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using an array as an icon map instead:

**PHP:**

```
$icon_map = array(
    'elektrisch-rijden' => 'icon--scooter',
    'efficient-laden'   => 'icon--battery',
    'stadshubs'         => 'icon--logistiek',
);

$icon_class = isset( $icon_map[ $theme_measure_icon->slug ] ) ? $icon_map[ $theme_measure_icon->slug ]  : '';
```

**HTML:**

```
<i class="icon <?= $icon_class; ?>"></i>
```

Then, to add or remove icons available, you need only amend the `$icon_map` array.

Note my use of [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to first check to see if an appropriate icon is in the array, avoiding undefined offset warnings.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you. It's not - but I copied it from the question so it'll stay :)

Answer (score 2):

Defining an associative array with the values you could get depending on the slug is much simpler/readable IMO:

```
$classes = [
    'elektrisch-rijden' => 'icon--scooter',
    'efficient-laden' => 'icon--battery',
    'stadshubs' => 'icon--logistiek',
];

<i class="icon <?= $classes[$theme_measure_icon->slug] ?>"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this next approach to achieve what you are looking for with a switch statement.

```
switch ($theme_measure_icon->slug) {
  case 'elektrisch-rijden':
    $icon_class = 'icon--scooter';
    break;
  case 'efficient-laden':
    $icon_class = 'icon--battery';
    break;
  case 'stadshubs':
    $icon_class = 'icon--logistiek';
    break;
  default:
    // code to be executed for your default icon class, you can remove this if you don't want it there
}

 <i class="icon <?= $icon_class; ?>"></i>
```